# Replacing a string by a tuple value in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, list-comprehension

This is my first post/question here on stackoverflow!

I have an issue when trying to replace an emoticon (that is contained in a list within a tuple). Here is the code:

```
emoticons = [('SMILE',[':-)', ':)', '(:', '(-:']),
        ('LAUGH',[':-D', ':D', 'X-D', 'XD', 'xD']),
        ('LOVE', ['<3', ':\*']),
        ('WINK', [';-)', ';)', ';-D', ';D', '(;', '(-;']),
        ('FROWN', [':-(', ':(', '(:', '(-:']),
        ('CRY', [':,(', ':\'(', ':"(', ':(('])]


def token_to_emot(token):
    for (emoji, smileys) in emoticons:
        if token in smileys:
            converted = token.replace(token, emoji)
            return converted
        else:
            return token

sample_tweet = ['It', 'was', 'amazing', ':)']
processed_tweet = [token_to_emot(token) for token in sample_tweet]
print(processed_tweet)
```

The first try produced the expected output:

```
['It', 'was', 'amazing', 'SMILE']
```

However, if I test it with smileys from the remaining tuples, the code does not work and emojis are not converted. Could someone help me find out what is wrong with the list comprehension here? Or maybe suggest another approach to converting emojis to strings?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in "else" statement

```
def token_to_emot(token):
  for (emoji, smileys) in emoticons:
      if token in smileys:
          converted = token.replace(token, emoji)
          return converted
      else:
          return token
```

You return token if smiley is not found in first smileys array.

Modify it to :-

```
def token_to_emot(token):
  for (emoji, smileys) in emoticons:
      if token in smileys:
          converted = token.replace(token, emoji)
          return converted
  else:
      return token 
      # return token only and only if token!=smileys for all emoticons
```

Also, you could also use:-

```
sample_tweet = ['It', 'was', 'amazing', ':)']
processed_tweet = list(map(token_to_emot, sample_tweet))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine, too! I tried different solutions but was a backspace away from finding it =]

Answer (score 0):

You return on the first iteration of the loop whether or not the emoticon is found.
Instead, you should first finish iterating through the entire `emoticons` list and only return the unconverted token if no replacement was found:

```
def token_to_emot(token):
    for (emoji, smileys) in emoticons:
        if token in smileys:
            converted = token.replace(token, emoji)
            return converted

    # Note this is AFTER the for loop is exhausted.    
    return token
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. It seems I need to brush up on list comprehension a bit!

Comment: @bart The list comprehension part of your code is just fine. The `token_to_emot` function just had a bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `dictionary` for this, as it will run substantially faster, especially the more tweets you process.  Additionally, you can use a nifty, readable list comprehension to reduce your code substantially.

A note regarding speed:

1. Your current program has to iterate over every emoji (`O(n)`) for every token inside the string (`O(n)`).  Making the algorithm `O(n^2)`.  Yours is technically more like `O(ne)` where n is the number of tokens and e is the number of unique emojis. So, it's not literally O(n^2).  But I was using this to explain the efficiency difference.
2. However, in my code, we have to make a dictionary check (which is `O(1)`) per token.  This makes mine `O(n)`, which makes a substantial difference when you are processing tweets by the masses.

## Code

```
emoticons = [('SMILE',[':-)', ':)', '(:', '(-:']),
        ('LAUGH',[':-D', ':D', 'X-D', 'XD', 'xD']),
        ('LOVE', ['<3', ':\*']),
        ('WINK', [';-)', ';)', ';-D', ';D', '(;', '(-;']),
        ('FROWN', [':-(', ':(', '(:', '(-:']),
        ('CRY', [':,(', ':\'(', ':"(', ':(('])]

emoticonDi = {e:string for string,emoji in emoticons for e in emoji}

import re
def convert_emoji(string):
    sample_tweet = string.split(" ")
    processed_tweet = [emoticonDi[v] if v in emoticonDi else v for v in sample_tweet]
    return processed_tweet

print(convert_emoji('It was amazing :)'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and an explanation! Some feedback about whether the original code could be improved was something I was looking for, too!